# Select preference between different facts

Tags: clips

I have to make a rule who choose the best phone line rate between 3 of them. The rates have different packs, such to have TV or a better Internet Connection.
When a clients want to upgrade it, it starts a petition with the internet connection it wants and if it wants TV.
The system has to choose the minimum rate there is avalible for the petition, namely, it couldn't choose a higher rate if there is a lower one who satisfies the conditions.

Is it possible to do it using only **one rule**? What I have right now choose always the highest rate, because for some reason it always have a higher preference.

```
(defrule cambio-tarifa

    ?dirPeticion <- ( peticion ( id_cliente ?id_cliente ) ( fibra ?fibra_minima ) ( TV ?TV_Peticion ) )
    ?dirCliente <- ( cliente ( id ?id_cliente ) ( plan ?plan_actual ) )

    ( plan ( nombre ?plan_nuevo ) ( precio ?precio_plan ) ( fibra ?fibra ) ( TV ?TV_Plan ) )
    ( plan ( nombre ?plan_actual ) ( precio ?precio_actual ) )

    ( test ( > ?precio_plan ?precio_actual ) )
    ( test ( >= ?fibra ?fibra_minima ) )  

    =>

    ( modify ?dirCliente ( plan ?plan_nuevo ) )
    ( retract ?dirPeticion )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the general pattern for a rule which selects the lowest/highest value:

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate plan 
   (slot id)
   (slot price))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts plans
   (plan (id A) (price 100))
   (plan (id B) (price 90))
   (plan (id C) (price 200))
   (plan (id D) (price 150)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule lowest
   (plan (id ?id) (price ?price))
   (not (plan (price ?price2&:(< ?price2 ?price))))
   =>
   (printout t "Plan " ?id " has the lowest price: " ?price crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Plan B has the lowest price: 90
CLIPS>
```